# Writing STL like iterator

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, iterator, operators

I was trying to learn writing stl like iterators, for that I wrote a simple circular array and added an iterator in it. Please look at the bottom of the code to see the problem.

```
template<typename T, int N>
class RingQueue{
    T * _marray;
    int _mbegin;
    int _msize;
public:
    RingQueue(){
        _marray = new T[N];
        _mbegin = 0;
        _msize= 0;
    }   
    void push_back(const T& val){
        if(_msize!=N){
            _marray[(_mbegin+_msize)%N] = val;
            _msize++;
        }
        else
            throw "Queue Full";
    }   
    T pop_front(){
        if(_msize!=0){
            T&val = _marray[_mbegin];
            _mbegin = (_mbegin+1)%N;
            _msize--;
            return val;
        }
        else
            throw "Queue Empty";
    }

    class iterator{
        RingQueue<T,N>* _container;
        int _idx;
        public:
        iterator(RingQueue<T,N>* container,int idx):_container(container){
            _idx = idx;
        }

        bool operator==(iterator &rhs){
            return (this->_container==rhs._container && this->_idx == rhs._idx);
        }
        bool operator!=(iterator &rhs){
            return !(*this==rhs);
        }   
        T operator*(){
            if(_container->_msize>0&&_idx<_container->_msize){
                return _container->_marray[(_container->_mbegin+_idx)%N];
            }
        }

        iterator& operator++(){
            if(_container->_msize ==0){
                *this = _container->end();
                return *this;
            }
            if(_idx==_container->_msize){   
                *this = _container->end();
                return *this;
            }
            _idx++;
            return *this;
        }
    };
    iterator begin(){
        return iterator(this,0);
    }
    iterator end(){
        return iterator(this,_msize);
    }
};
int current=0;
int gen(){
    return current++;
}

int curr_op=0;
int operation(){
    return 2*(curr_op++&1)-1;
}
int main(){
    RingQueue<int,10> ring;
    vector<int> v(9),op(9);
    generate(v.begin(),v.end(),gen);
    random_shuffle(v.begin(),v.end());
    copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));    
    cout<<endl;

    generate(op.begin(),op.end(),operation);        
    random_shuffle(op.begin(),op.end());
    // copy(op.begin(),op.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));   
    cout<<endl;

    for(vector<int>::iterator itv  = v.begin();itv!=v.end();itv++){
        try{
            ring.push_back(*itv);   
        }catch(const char * e){
            cout<<*itv<<e<<endl;
        }
    }
    //works
    RingQueue<int,10>::iterator ite = ring.end();
    for(RingQueue<int,10>::iterator it = ring.begin(); it!=ite; ++it){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
    // doesn't work 
    for(RingQueue<int,10>::iterator it = ring.begin(); it!=ring.end(); ++it){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the doesn't work part, g++ dumps the following error

```
ringqueue.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ringqueue.cpp:112: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘it != ring.RingQueue<T, N>::end [with T = int, int N = 10]()’
ringqueue.cpp:48: note: candidates are: bool RingQueue<T, N>::iterator::operator!=(RingQueue<T, N>::iterator&) [with T = int, int N = 10]
```

the works part compiles seamlessly, when compiled without doesn't work part. Can somebody explain me what's wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the issue is in these lines:

```
    bool operator==(iterator &rhs){
        return (this->_container==rhs._container && this->_idx == rhs._idx);
    }
    bool operator!=(iterator &rhs){
        return !(*this==rhs);
    }
```

The problem here is that these functions take in lvalue references to their arguments.  This means that if you try passing an rvalue (for example, a temporary object returned from a function) into these operators, you will get a compile-time error because references cannot bind to temporaries.  To fix this, either change the arguments to be const references:

```
    bool operator==(const iterator &rhs){
        return (this->_container==rhs._container && this->_idx == rhs._idx);
    }
    bool operator!=(const iterator &rhs){
        return !(*this==rhs);
    }
```

Since const references can bind to temporaries, or have them take their arguments by value:

```
    bool operator==(iterator rhs){
        return (this->_container==rhs._container && this->_idx == rhs._idx);
    }
    bool operator!=(iterator rhs){
        return !(*this==rhs);
    }
```

Whichever choice you make, you should probably mark these functions `const` because they don't mutate the receiver object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah shouldn't have missed that, had faced a similar problem before as well. Thanks a lot. One more thing, can you also explain the error message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, int N>
class RingQueue{
    T * _marray;
    int _mbegin;
    int _msize;
public:
    RingQueue(){
        _marray = new T[N];
        _mbegin = 0;
        _msize= 0;
    }   
    void push_back(const T& val){
        if(_msize!=N){
            _marray[(_mbegin+_msize)%N] = val;
            _msize++;
        }
        else
            throw "Queue Full";
    }   
    T pop_front(){
        if(_msize!=0){
            T&val = _marray[_mbegin];
            _mbegin = (_mbegin+1)%N;
            _msize--;
            return val;
        }
        else
            throw "Queue Empty";
    }

    class iterator{
        RingQueue<T,N>* _container;
        int _idx;
        public:
        iterator(RingQueue<T,N>* container,int idx):_container(container){
            _idx = idx;
        }

        bool operator==(iterator rhs){ // XXX do not pass it as a reference
            return (this->_container==rhs._container && this->_idx == rhs._idx);
        }
        bool operator!=(iterator rhs){ // XXX do not pass it as a reference
            return !(*this==rhs);
        }   
        T operator*(){
            if(_container->_msize>0&&_idx<_container->_msize){
                return _container->_marray[(_container->_mbegin+_idx)%N];
            }
            throw "XXX"; // XXX missing return statement
        }

        iterator& operator++(){
            if(_container->_msize ==0){
                *this = _container->end();
                return *this;
            }
            if(_idx==_container->_msize){   
                *this = _container->end();
                return *this;
            }
            _idx++;
            return *this;
        }
    };
    iterator begin(){
        return iterator(this,0);
    }
    iterator end(){
        return iterator(this,_msize);
    }
};
int current=0;
int gen(){
    return current++;
}

int curr_op=0;
int operation(){
    return 2*(curr_op++&1)-1;
}
int main(){
    RingQueue<int,10> ring;
    vector<int> v(9),op(9);
    generate(v.begin(),v.end(),gen);
    random_shuffle(v.begin(),v.end());
    copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));    
    cout<<endl;

    generate(op.begin(),op.end(),operation);        
    random_shuffle(op.begin(),op.end());
    // copy(op.begin(),op.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));   
    cout<<endl;

    for(vector<int>::iterator itv  = v.begin();itv!=v.end();itv++){
        try{
            ring.push_back(*itv);   
        }catch(const char * e){
            cout<<*itv<<e<<endl;
        }
    }
    for(RingQueue<int,10>::iterator it = ring.begin(); it!=ring.end(); ++it){
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code is working. look for XXX mark ;)

Comment: You should generally avoid passing entire objects, that makes answer from templatetypedef a better answer. Nonetheless I should have tried your approach as well. Thanks

Comment: well, I said my solution is working, and pointed out what's wrong. I never said that was the best solution ;) but I voted up for templatetypedef too ;)

Answer (score 0):

When writing iterators for custom containers, you might find it helpful to use [boost::iterator_facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html). It's a library that allows you to define just the basic operations of your iterator (increment, dereference, and equality comparison, and, if applicable, decrement and advance) and fills in the blanks for you by providing all the required operators. Here's how your iterator might look using boost::iterator_facade:

```
class iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<iterator, T, boost::forward_traversal_tag>{
    RingQueue<T,N>* _container;
    int _idx;
public:
    iterator(RingQueue<T,N>* container,int idx):_container(container){
        _idx = idx;
    }

    bool equal(const iterator &rhs) const {
        return (this->_container==rhs._container && this->_idx == rhs._idx);
    }

    T dereference() const {
        if(_container->_msize>0&&_idx<_container->_msize){
            return _container->_marray[(_container->_mbegin+_idx)%N];
        }
    }

    void increment(){
        if(_container->_msize ==0)
            *this = _container->end();
        else if(_idx==_container->_msize)
            *this = _container->end();
        else
            _idx++;
    }
};
```

`boost::forward_traversal_tag` specifies the iterator traversal - it means you can only use the iterator to traverse the container in the forward direction, and stepping only one element at a time.